# Analysis of ratio between two functions

Tags: analysis

Say I have two functions-f(x) and g(x) ( continuous differentiable and nice), then how do I find the domain of 'x' such that the following inequality is satisfied:

$$ \frac{ f(x)}{g(x) } <1$$

example: $$ \frac{x^n}{n!} <1$$

for a given 'n', where do I find where this ratio becomes less than one?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $g(x)>0$, you can rewrite as

$$f(x)-g(x)\le0,$$

which is directly related to the search for the roots of $f-g$. Depending on the nature of $f-g$, the resolution can be done analytically, or require numerical methods.

---

$$x^n=n!$$ is special because the factorial is a discrete function. For small $x$, the best is just to try increasing values of $n$, starting after $x$. For large $x$, you can use the Stirling approximation

$$n!\approx\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n=x^n$$ which is grossly solved by

$$n=ex.$$

To get the exact value, you can explore the integers below $ex$.

---

Another way to look at it is to tabulate the limit values of $x$, i.e. those for which you must increase $n$. They are

$$x_n=\sqrt[n]{n!}.$$

Comment: is there no systematic approach to this problem?

Comment: if f(x) has root at point 'a' that does imply anythibg about the root of g(x), so how does this difference in equality help us?

Comment: @DDD4C4U: no, there is no systematic approach. And the roots of $f$ and $g$ are irrelevant to this problem. Only the sign of $f-g$ matters.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you may want to solve the next equation:
$$\frac{x^n}{n!}\leqslant 1 $$
First of all, I assume that $n$ is non-negative integer. It follows that $n!$ is positive integer, so now I can write that
$$x^n\leqslant n!$$
Then, answer: if $n$ is even then $x\in [-\sqrt[n]{n!},+\sqrt[n]{n!}]$; otherwise, if $n$ is odd, then $x\in [-\infty,+\sqrt[n]{n!}]$.

My answer is correct in some aspect, but you may need something else, do you need exactly what I've just wrote?